# Mac - Linear interpolation not working

Tags: opengl, textures, texture2d

I searched a lot and just can't seem to find anything on this topic. I got a Macbook with OpenGL 4.1. I create a Texture with:

```
glGenTextures(1, &heightMapTexture);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, heightMapTexture);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 13);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_MIRRORED_REPEAT);
glUniform1i(program1->uniformLocation("heightMap"), 0);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16UI, heightMap.getWidth(), heightMap.getHeight(), 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, heightMap.getData().data());
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

This works fine but I actually would like to use GL_LINEAR. But GL_LINEAR gives me a texture with all zeros / black.

**Does Mac just not support GL_LINEAR or is there an extension for it?**
In the official documentation i found the following piece of code:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB,
                GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

(https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_texturedata/opengl_texturedata.html)

But I can't get the extension to work either.

Comment: Are you generating mipmaps somewhere?? GL_LINEAR expects no mipmaps, so try maybe removing everything related to mipmap gen (levels, etc..)

Comment: Yes I do as I said it works like it is now and when I change GL_NEAREST to GL_LINEAR it does not anymore. (I checked without mipmapping as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GL_R16UI` is an integer texture format. OpenGL does not support linear filtering of integer formats.

From section 8.17 "Texture Completeness" of the OpenGL 4.5 spec, page 252:

> Using the preceding deﬁnitions, a texture is complete unless any of the following conditions hold true:
>   [..]
>   The internal format of the texture is integer [..] and either the magnification filter is not NEAREST, or the minification filter is neither NEAREST nor NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST.

To use texures with 16-bit per component precision that you can sample with linear filtering, you'll need to use a normalized format like `GL_R16`, or go all the way to a float with `GL_R32F`.

Answer (score 2):

Mac definitely supports bi-linear and tri-linear filtering in OpenGL - it's been part of the core spec for a very long time. The code you have shown for uploading the texture:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R16UI, heightMap.getWidth(), heightMap.getHeight(), 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, heightMap.getData().data());
```

Uses `0` as the second parameter, which corresponds to the base-level image (sometimes referred to as the top mipmap). You don't show any code for uploading the other possible mip levels of the texture, nor using are you using `glGenerateTextureMipmap` or `glGenerateMipmap`. In this case, the behavior is undefined in the GL spec, although most of the time it just results in a black texture sample. Likely turning on `GL_LINEAR` is causing you to sample these undefined texture levels, resulting in the black sample.

You should either define these texture levels with additional calls to `glTexImage2D`, and/or restrict the texture parameters to the actual mip levels your texture will contain.

Comment: I use glGenerateMipmap right after glTexImage2D. I confirmed that the miplevels are correctly loaded to the gpu (with textureLod()). I think you are right I must miss some sort of initialization...